# as ... as - "African-American culture as embodied in music, art, and literature flourished as never before."

Tags: comparison, as, comparative

(a)

> African-American culture **as** embodied in music, art, and literature flourished **as** never before.

Is this sentence above an example of "**as** ... **as**"?

Or is it an example of ellipsis? What words are left out to avoid repetition?

Such as

(a*)

> African-American culture **as** (which was) embodied in music, art, and literature flourished **as** (this culture) never (flourished) before.

Comment: This was several questions in one, which is off-topic for this site. The question about the two "as" seems to be the main question, so I'm removing the request to proofread and compare the three versions below your first question. If you want to know whether your other versions mean the same thing, you can ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a comparison between two things, if I understand what you mean by "as ... as".

(c) is the closest in meaning to the original sentence.

(b) has a slightly different meaning. It seems to note, incidentally, that African-American culture happens to be embodied in those things, without specifically qualifying the exact sort of culture we are discussing.

(a) does not really make much sense.

To break down this complex sentence:

- African-American culture

  - as embodied in

    - music, art, and literature
- flourished

  - as never before

It would be more clear, I think, if we re-allocated some optional commas:

> African-American culture, as embodied in music, art and literature, flourished as never before.

Or instead, with parentheses:

> African-American culture (as embodied in music, art, and literature) flourished as never before.

By the way, the punctuation `...` [is called an ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), not to be confused with the concept you asked about :)

Comment: :) Indeed. The book Practical English Usage calls "avoiding repeating information" ellipsis. I didn't invent a puzzle to confuse two concepts of ellipsis. Appreciate your discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an example of "as ... as".

It's simply a sentence that happens to use the word "as" twice.

It means roughly:

> African-American culture, **which was** embodied in music, art, and literature, flourished as **it had** never **flourished** before.

Comment: The word **as** is used twice. Is the first **as** equal to *which was*? Or could we express the same meaning of the original sentence in the form of [**as** it was embodied] or [**as** which was embodied]?

Comment: @StatsCruncher "As" and "which was" are not exactly the same, but they're close enough to demonstrate that (1) the two "as" do not from an "as...as" pair, and (2) the first "as" doesn't have anything elided.